# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular,I am storing the user details in the localStorage with the name currentUser,
It is working perfectly upto 30 back, now it is showing the forllowing error.

[image]

I am getting the error in constructor.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

I have added the roles recently

```
export class User {
    userid: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    roles: string[];
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `localStorage.getItem('currentUser')`? Is it the *string* `[object Object]` by any chance?

Comment: @VLAZ it is [object Object] only

Comment: So, that's the problem. It's not valid. You should be turning the object into JSON when you put it in local storage - `localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user))`

Comment: I am storing using the same `localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: Then you have to check what `res` is. That might be a string `"[object Object]"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON.stringify and then store it in localStorage

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(res); // the one you get
localStorage.setItem("currentUser", obj);
```

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam then give us more insight on what "res" is returning

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam may be add a console.log